# Jquery Popup Closing the current Page and exiting to index page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a page in Jquery Mobile with PhoneGap .I have added Popup menu to choose the options to take the picture from Camera,Album

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu" data-theme="b" id="popupsign">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:210px;">
        <li data-role="list-divider">Choose an action</li>
        <li><a href="#" id="fromCamera">Camera</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="fromAlbum">Album</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="cancelPopup">Cancel</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

When I am choosing any one of the option or clicking outSide of the Page .it closing.exiting the current page.

```
 $("#popupsign" ).popup( "close" );
```

Comment: So what (fromCamera, fromAlbum, cancelPopup) exactly do?

Comment: it will trigger the Camera plugin to take the picture using PhoneGap

Comment: maybe that's problem. replace them with proper links and see if you still get the issue. That way you know is something to do with cordova